# Warning "Referenced assembly targets a different processor than the application"

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

Welcome,
I was programming 32Bit Application then I needed it to be 64bit I've changed "Platform target" and "Active Solution Platform" to x64.

But I have a problem.I get These Warnings

```
Warning 1   Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
Warning 2   Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Data.dll' targets a different processor
```

Note : I can't make it "Any CPU" because I use "System.Data.SQLite.dll".

And Thanks

Comment: Why you can't make it Any CPU? I can't get it. Can't you just deploy correct System.Data.SQLite.dll version and keep your application CPU independent? (you may need to fix project file manually, see solutions suggested, for example, for SharpDX)

Comment: this Dll was supported only 32-bit or 64-bit , If you can give me the correct version I'll be Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. You have both versions? 32 AND 64? Reference right one for you machine but deploy right one for target machine...(and ignore that warnings).

Comment: i have referenced 64-bit only and when i ignore that warnings it doesn't work on another 64-bit PC

Comment: Your machine is 64 bit, you referenced 64 bit, you built for 64 bit, you deployed 64 bit...and it doesn't work on another 64 bit? There should be something else!!! Check/post error you get there

Comment: my machine 32 bit and i referenced SQLite only for 64 bit